# How do I hide the video panel on the YouTube live streaming dashboard?

Tags: youtube

While streaming live on YouTube, the video is playing (or buffering) on the [live dashboard](https://www.youtube.com/live_dashboard). Ultimately during game streaming, I only want to see the chat but not the video feed (I don't want to waste bandwidth on it).

How can I hide the video feed but see the chat?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a DOM editor (Chrome has one built in) and delete the element. Unsure if this stops "streaming" though.